# python array subrange efficiency

Tags: python, arrays, performance

I have an array (vector, matrix) type that I use subrange on a lot. For example:

```
x = x + y[i:j]
```

Does the `y[i:j]` create a temporary copy before passing the argument to the addition operator?

Thanks!

Comment: Are we talking about Python array from the array module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) or NumPy arrays (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)?

Comment: Any reason for avoiding the use of either `+=` or `.extend`?

Comment: Reason: I was not aware that += and .extend would be better... I thought += is just syntactic sugar. (Also this is existing code I have to take over.) Are they? Maybe they make fewer temp copies, exactly what I need?